# Cursor won't populate in input field when trying to unlock mac HD

Tags: software-update, error, recovery-hd

I'm updating my mother's macbook because she was on el capitan. I initially tried directly updating to Catalina to no avail. Then I updated to mojave to try to update to catalina. That worked and when I tried updating to catalina, the screen went black with the not allowed symbol on the screen. I tried doing the command+R to redownload mojave again but when I get to the point of where I want to save mojave, input field won't work. Anyone know how to fix this? [image: cursor won't populate and the keyboard won't work]

Comment: Can you tab into the input instead of using the trackpad?

Comment: I tried that as well! I couldn't even do that. Any ideas on how to get that field populated?